# Looking for a single word

Tags: meaning

I am looking for a word that describes someone who says something to you but when talking to someone else says the complete opposite.

For example: if someone said they loved a color of a vehicle but when talking to others they say they hated it.

Comment: If you want something other than "dishonest", you might need to expand on the circumstances where this word applies.

Comment: 'Dishonest', 'inconsistent' ...

Comment: Hi, and welcome to English Language & Usage. Could you edit your post to have a more meaningful title (perhaps: Single word for speaking differently to different people")? (This would make it easier for other readers to decide whether they'd like to pursue further.) Also please give examples of what words you have researched (and decided were close) as well as why you rejected others. (This helps keep us from having to guess.)

Comment: Without further context, this should be closed as inadequately construed, **not answered**. If the required word is 'hypocrite' / ''two-faced', this is a duplicate. If it is 'befuddled', this is for ELL. Anything else is probably better on Medical Sciences SE.

Answer (score 1):

I think, the most appropriate word to describe such person will be **[hypocrite](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/hypocrite)**:

> a person who pretends to be what he is not

Also good word will be **[phoney](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/phoney)**:

> an insincere or pretentious person, a fake

You can also look for some translations [here](https://www.multitran.com/m.exe?s=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BA&l1=2&l2=1) and [here](https://www.multitran.com/m.exe?l1=2&l2=1&s=%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80&langlist=1).

And finally, you can use an idiom: **[say something behind someone's back](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/say+something+behind+someone%27s+back)**.

Answer (score 1):

A person who expresses one thing to one person and the opposite to another
is **two-faced**.

> 2. figurative. Deceitful, insincere: = double-faced adj.
>
> 1864   in J. H. Newman Apol. v. 429   Two-faced persons, who did not go simply and straightforwardly to work.

[Oxford English Dictionary](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/208225?redirectedFrom=two+faced#eid)

> BGT judge branded 'two-faced' by Piers Morgan

[Daily Express 23 November 2019](https://www.express.co.uk/celebrity-news/1207835/David-Walliams-Piers-Morgan-Britains-Got-Talent-Twitter-spat-Jonathan-Ross-Show-news)